# How can I read the POST data in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am creating the below url request which launches a flex application through the mentioned url. I have also added data and set url req method to POST. How can I read this POST data in my Flex Application which is being launched

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.id = 'abc';
urlReq.data = requestVars;
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlReq.url = '../../bin-debug/FlexApp.html';
navigateToURL(urlReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

The POST data is sent to the server, so if you want to read it on `FlexApp.html` from the client then the server needs to echo it back on that page somehow. Otherwise you could use a GET request and access the request parameters using JavaScript `window.location.search`.

Here's an example using PHP to output the POST variables as JSON to the page:

```
<script>
var post_params = <? echo json_encode($_POST); ?>
function getPostParam(name){
    return post_params[name];
}
</script>
```

Call from JavaScript:

```
alert(getPostParam("id"));
```

Call from ActionScript:

```
trace(ExternalInterface.call("getPostParam", "id"));
```

Comment: I dont want to use a GET request, as my data can be big and I dont want it in the url as well. Any suggestion how can I make the server echo back the POST data.

Comment: I have tried adding the following javascript code in my index.template.html to echo back POST data but after adding this code, my application just shows a blank page. I am using Safari browser.

var my_javascript_variable = <?php echo $_POST['id'];?>;
function getMyVar() {return my_javascript_variable;
}

Comment: Updated my answer with an example using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass your variables within the url and then use flashvars via [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to pass them to the target app?

I've had more or less similar issue, and used this method.

1. In my first swf:

   ```
   var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(String("game.html?user_id="+userId+"&user_code="+userCode));
   ```
2. And then in game.html I parsed those variables and sent then as flashvars:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function getUrlVars() {
       var vars = {};
       var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
       function(m,key,value) {
         vars[key] = value;
       });
       return vars;
   };

   var flashvars = {
     user_id: getUrlVars()["user_id"],
     user_code: getUrlVars()["user_code"]
   };
   var params = {
       quality: "high",
       bgcolor: "#000000",
       play: "true",
       loop: "true",
       wmode: "window",
       scale: "showall",
       menu: "true",
       devicefont: "false",
       allowScriptAccess: "true"
   };

   swfobject.embedSWF("preloader.swf", "flashContent", "980", "663", "11.2.0",false, flashvars, params);
   </script>
   ```
3. And finally in my target swf I received them like this:

   ```
   var userId:String = loaderInfo.parameters.user_id as String;
   var userCode:String = loaderInfo.parameters.user_code as String;
   ```

I hope this helps, and if not, then I probably didn't understand the main issue.

Comment: I dont want the data to get shown in the url actually. Therefore, I want to use POST method.

Comment: Ahh ok, sorry, I didn't notice your comment to the other answer. You could surely make it over-complex and insert the data into e.g. mySql database and dig it from there in your target app. But if you find a simple solution for your issue, I'd love to hear it too! :)